# Partial order relations definition

Tags: real-analysis, relations

Okay by definition :

A relation $≤$ on a set $P$ is a partial order or linear order if it is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive.

The thing I don't understand is,

$≤$ is always reflexive,antisymmetric and transitive. So Does that mean that every Set $P$ is partially ordered? What is the purpose of using "if" in the definition above then?

Comment: Here $\leq$ doesn't necessarily mean the less-than-or-equal-to relation on a subset of real numbers.  It is just some relation on some set.  A partial order behaves just like $\leq$ on numbers, so we reuse the symbol.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: It does not satisfy *all* the properties of $\le$ on numbers. In particular, for two different numbers $a$ and $b$, we always have either of $a\le b$ or $b\le a$. For a partial order, that's not necessarily the case; that's why it is called *partial* order.

Comment: @celtschk: You are, of course, correct.  I was being a bit sloppy.  I should have said a partial order behaves *very much* like $\leq$ on real numbers.

Comment: To answer your question, every set $P$ **of real numbers** is partially ordered, because less-than-or-equal-to on $\mathbb{R}$ is a partial order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question like this when I took linear algebra about the word "if" in a definition.

As @MatthewLeingang says, $\leq$ isn't our usual symbol like in $\mathbb{R}$, it is a placeholder. We may take it to be $\subset$ if we wish.

Now to the real question: the word "if" is just to signify the defining property. For example, here's a fake definition:

> An object is called **spoofy** if it is green and plays music.

The conjunction "if" is just used to join the object's name to its defining properties.

Comment: Shouldn't he had told us that it is not the usual symbol like in R in the course though. It's a bit confusing

Comment: This placeholder idea is common in mathematics. For example, in abstract algebra, $*$ is a common symbol to use for operations on groups if we wish to define an abstract operation. You'll have to get used to these and spot them.